# rigidity of $\mathcal P(\omega_1) / NS$ under MA

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, boolean-algebras

In Woodin's book, Lemma 5.100 asserts that if $MA_{\omega_1}$ holds and there is an $\omega_2$-saturated ideal $I$ on $\omega_1$, then $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/I$ is a rigid boolean algebra, meaning it has no nontrivial automorphisms.  He states that this is well-known, so my question is, where else does it appear in the literature?  I would like to find a different proof.

Comment: This seems to be a refinement of what one finds in the Martin's Maximum paper (see around Theorem 18). I do not know of an actual source for Lemma 5.100, though.

Comment: It also appears in my paper 'A uniqueness theorem for iterations' (maybe only for the nonstationary ideal, but I think the proof works in general).